# Bitmap re-sizing without being told to?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

Please excuse me if I'm doing something really stupid, but I'm a little new at actionscript, and graphics programming in general. I'm trying to make an online TCG and I'm starting out by creating the table and card stacks. I've set it up where I have a table which holds stacks. The stacks hold cards, and the cards hold a front and back image. Really simple. So I thought. For some reason, the card is re-sizing to fit the screen. Even though a trace shows that the width and height are correct. Here is an example:

[image]

In all reality, it should be about the height of the white box with the "A" in it, in the top left hand corner. The only place where I explicitly set a width and height is setting the table width and height. The table, Stack, and card are all sublasses of the flash Sprite class. Since there are 4 seperate files for the example above, if someone would need to look at the code, please let me know what you'd be looking for so I know what to share.

Comment: I think you should post the part of your code where you are loading the card and add it to the display list.

Comment: Show us how and where you're adding the cards to the stage please.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QnwjCUA6 that's where it's added. I pass the table as a parameter to stack, and the stack adds itself. Then I add a card to the stack, and becomes a 2 tier child to the table.

Comment: Show us the Card class, the Table class and the Stack class as they're all connected.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/kZ6ezatV that's all 3 classes

Comment: And now the PaperSprite class please.

Comment: @LordZardeck, you can post post your code here. It's easier for everybody to read.

Comment: Are you using scaleX or scaleY anywhere? Or changing the transform of any display object?

Comment: I use scale code when displaying and hiding the card, but it never is called. as for the transform, I don't believe so. The PaperSprite class might though. I'll upload it.

Comment: PaperSprite class: http://pastebin.com/bU6umCq7

Comment: Nothing that you showed seems to be scaling. Do the following: add just the front bitmap directly to the stage and find out what happens and then add just the papersprite to the stage and see what happens also.

Comment: both of those actions renders it correctly

Comment: Remove the table.width and table.height atributions and see what happens.

Comment: yep. that fixes it. great. so how can I have my table fill the screen but not affect the cards? Also, why would it be pushing it's width and height on it's children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're scaling table by changing it's width and height. When you scale a parent, all of it's children get also scaled.

You should only scale the background bitmap you create. The size (width and height) of a parent will be the area contained by it's children.

Comment: so by resizing the background, it will "push" the table container to be that large?

Comment: Precisely. The size of the parent is the area it's children use. A display object will always increase in size if you add a bigger child. You basically shouldn't set the width and height of something unless you want to scale it.

Comment: Ahh, ok! +1 for helping me learn more! Like i said, I'm relatively new to the actionscript scene, so I don't really know much. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I wanted to double-check first and make sure I got the results I was looking for. Great help!

Comment: Another option is to override the width and height setters if you have exact dimensions that need to be maintained.  The Flex SDK is representative of this method for preserving layouts when children larger then their parents are added to the display hierarchy.